# Maverick's installation: Can i install Mavericks on a non-case-sensitive partition?

Tags: macos, imac, disk-format, adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to install photoshop on my iMac but it looks like I can't install Mavericks if I have a case-sensitive partition. Is it a known bug? Can I do anything to fix it?

Comment: What suggests you can not install OS X 10.9, Mavericks, on a case-sensitive partition?

Comment: Could you clarify what install is causing you a problem: Mavericks or Photoshop?
The subject of your question doesn't look like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/247920/install-adobe-cs5-on-mac-with-case-sensitive-filesystem) on how to install Adobe CS products on case sensitives partitions :

- you can copy over an existing install on a case-sensitive filesystem and rename all the folders so they match.
- Or Follow [this procedure](https://bitbucket.org/lokkju/adobe_case_sensitive_volumes) which seems to work with CS5.5, CS6 & CC.

An for your title question : Yes Mavericks can be install on non-case-sensitive partition. It't the default situation used by Apple on new Macs.

Answer (score 0):

> > > > Or Follow this procedure which seems to work with CS5.5, CS6 & CC.

This procedure does not work on Mavericks because function which used in this scripts 'FSGetVolumeParms' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.8

Hello to you from Abode :P

Comment: Please consider editing this in to the other answer. It helps explain options, but doesn't stand well alone as an answer...